# Jupyter Hub with MariaDB instead of SQLite

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook, mariadb, jupyter, jupyterhub

I try to replace SQLite by MariaDB on Jupyter Hub.
In the Jupyter Hub configuration file I changed:

`#c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'sqlite:///jupyterhub.sqlite'`

by

`c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}{}'.format("username","pwd","localhost","jupyterhub","")`

I've created an empty database "jupyterhub" with PhpMyAdmin, but when I launch Jupyter Hub, I have the following error message :

`Failed to connect to db: mysql+pymysql://username:pwd@localhost/jupyterhub`

"Username" and "pwd" are good, they work with PhpMyAmdin.

I've tried several things but no luck. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install mysql-connector

   ```
   pip3 install 'mysql-connector<2.2'
   ```
2. In Jupyter Hub config file:

   ```
   c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}{}'.format("username","pwd","127.0.0.1","jupyterhub","")
   ```
3. In MariaDB config file if version < 10.2.1

   ```
   [mysqld]
   innodb_file_format=Barracuda
   innodb_large_prefix=1
   ```